# How can I create a goal funnel that includes two different subdomains?

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I have two subdomains — `www.website.com` and `subdomain.website.com`. I'm currently using Universal Analytics which is handling the tracking of both beautifully. I now need to set up some goal funnels that all involve starting on `subdomain.website.com` and ending (Destination Page) on `wwww.website.com`.

Is this possible? I can't seem to find any tips on doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you tracking both of your subdomains with the same property? If so, you can build an advanced filter to show you the full URL and then create your goal funnel.

Filter Type: Custom filter > Advanced
Field A: Hostname
Extract A: (.*)
Field B: Request URI
Extract B: (.*)
Output To: Request URI
Constructor: $A1$B1

Comment: Thank you @maggieto! And how might I create the goal funnel once full URLs appear with this filter?

Comment: Once you have the full URL you'll just use your full URL for the funnel steps:
Step 1: www.website.com/page1
Step 2: subdomain.website.com/page2
etc.